# How to remove Label for attribute from checkBoxList in yii

Tags: yii

```
   $records_skincolor1 = array('Black'=> 'Black','Brown'=> 'Brown','Dark Brown'=> 'Dark Brown','Blue'=> 'Blue','Grey Blue'=> 'Grey Blue','Hazel'=> 'Hazel','True Green'=> 'True Green'); 
    echo CHtml::checkBoxList('Superadvancesearch[talent_skincolor][]','',$records_skincolor1, array(
        'template'=><li>{input}{label}</li>,
        'separator'=>'',

    ));
```

I need to remove label `for` attribute.  How to remove it.

Comment: Apart from the lack of '' around the `<li>{input}{template}</li>` what is not working with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Yii 1.1.14 you can use the new `beginLabel`, `labelTitle` and `endLabel` placeholder. In this case, no `for` will be rendered:

```
'template' => '{input}{beginLabel}{labelTitle}{endLabel}'
```

But to be honest I can hardly see a reason why you would want to remove this attribute. Because then you can't click the label anymore to check/uncheck a checkbox. Maybe your rather look for surrounding labels:

```
'template' => '{beginLabel}{input}{labelTitle}{endLabel}'
```

This is how Bootstrap expects checkboxes and here the label can still be clicked to check/uncheck the checkbox.

The same works for radiobuttons, too, BTW.

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai Then you got something wrong. It is working in 1.1.14, and even documented (see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBoxList-detail)).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

you are giving an array to your CHtml::checkBoxList method.

you just define the array before this method and make it with your condition.

```
if ($value == $someValue)
$yourArray=array(
    'template'=><li>{input}{label}</li>,
    'separator'=>'',);
else
$yourArray=array(
    'template'=><li>{input}</li>,
    'separator'=>'',);
```

and give this to your method:

```
echo CHtml::checkBoxList('Superadvancesearch[talent_skincolor][]','',$records_skincolor1, $yourArray
));
```

cheers.